# how to print the outcome of the 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, string, matrix, 2d

[the out come should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPGnn.jpg)

```
String word = "grumpy";
int size = word.length();
char[][] matrix = new char[size][size];
for(int i=0; i<size; i++ )
{
   matrix[0][i]=word.charAt(i);
   matrix[size-1][i]=word.charAt(size-1-i);
   matrix[i][size-1]=word.charAt(size-1-i);
   matrix[i][0]=word.charAt(i);
}
```

Please help.
I am having a problem how to print the outcome of my code it should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPGnn.jpg).

Comment: You're going to have to give us more details about what you're trying to accomplish and what isn't working if you want specific help.

Comment: I added a picture for how should the outcome look. I don't know how to print those outcome in java.

Comment: @Classic check the following answers...

Comment: I will try it as soon as possible my java is not functioning well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
   for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[i]).replaceAll(",","")
                                                   .replaceAll("\u0000"," "));
    }
```

This will gives you out put as,

```
[g r u m p y]
[r         p]
[u         m]
[m         u]
[p         r]
[y p m u r g]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) }
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if(i == 0 || i == size - 1 || j == 0 || j == size - 1) {
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + ' ');
        } else {
            System.out.print('  ');
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```